# Letters sliding in on background

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax, animate.css

I am trying to recreate something like this http://akce.kia.com/cz/.

If you click on a car you will see letters sliding in. Can somebody please explain what technologies are they using because whatever I do I cannot keep words and background picture on the same level. (You see how they follow the line)

I can make div to follow the line but as soon as you resize browser everything is messed up, and on that page everything resizes smoothly.

Can you please point me in the right direction, I am struggling with this for hours...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use animated SVG for it or several different layers (like divs) positioned absolutely (but as you noted already, this is not easy doing responsively).